# Using Imageshack's API

Tags: vb.net, api, imageshack

I have tried to make a uploader using imageshacks API but I have not been successful, I don't get an error code so I don't know what the error is.

This is their documentation: code.google.com/p/imageshackapi/wiki/ImageshackAPI
I have a imageshack api key too.

These are some of the websites/codes I have tried:

http://codeemporium.com/2009/06/14/dot-net-c-sharp-wrapper-for-the-imageshack-xml-api/

But none of them have a direct code that I use without having to change most of the code, which I am not good with, I don't have experience with API's.

**Edit: I still need help with it.**

Thanks

Comment: You can tell every one how you solve it with an answer and mark it as correct (green mark).